# Strongly typed rest parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I define dynamic strongly typed rest parameters with TypeScript 3.2?
Here's my use case:

```js
function exec<T, P extends ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping, E extends keyof P, U extends P[E]>(command: E, ...rest: U): U{
    return;
}

exec('cmd2', true, 1, 'hello');

interface ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping {
    ['cmd1']: [string];
    ['cmd2']: [boolean, number, string];
    ['cmd2']: [boolean, boolean];
}
```

At this point everything seems to work.
When writing args for `exec` with `cmd2`, I can see the compiler (typescript) providing typing information for the 3 args.
The return value is also correct...

However the things fall over at the line containing the declaration `...rest: U` for the rest parameters.

The error is simple: 
`A rest parameter must be of an array type.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `P extends ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping`, which means that `exec()` accepts any mapping that is a superset of the interface you've defined. This would allow non-array types. If you remove that constraint (and fix what I assume is a typo), you get no error messages.

```
interface ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping {
    ['cmd1']: [string];
    ['cmd2']: [boolean, number, string];
    ['cmd3']: [boolean, boolean];
}

type P = ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping;

function exec<T, E extends keyof P, U extends P[E]>(command: E, ...rest: U): U{
    return rest;
}

exec('cmd2', true, 1, 'hello');
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

`U` must be an array. We know `U` is a value of `P`, but there is no guarantee that all values of `P` are arrays. That's because `exec` depends not on the concrete `ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping` interface defined below, but on some `P` we don't fully know yet. And because we don't know it yet, we cannot trust it to follow the blueprint of `ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping` — after all, it might add some properties of its own which are not arrays.

**Solution**

The solution is to make sure all values — present and future — will always be arrays.

```
interface ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping {
    ['cmd1']: [string];
    ['cmd2']: [boolean, number, string];
    ['cmd3']: [boolean, boolean];
    [index: string]: any[]
}
```

That extra property is called *index signature*.

You can, of course, be more precise here and say `(string | number | boolean)[]` instead of `any[]`.

**Bonus points**

There are a few more mistakes in your code:

- Computed property name `cmd2` is duplicated
- The `T` type parameter is unused
- The `P` type parameter is incorrectly used (it is not used to describe parameters nor return types)
- `exec` promises to return `U`, but it's returning `undefined`

The corrected solution:

```
function exec<P extends ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping, E extends keyof P, U extends P[E]>(mapping: P, command: E, ...rest: U): U{
    return rest;
}

interface ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping {
    ['cmd1']: [string];
    ['cmd2']: [boolean, number, string];
    ['cmd3']: [boolean, boolean];
    [index: string]: any[]
}

declare const mapping: ICommandNameArgumentTypeMapping;

exec(mapping, 'cmd2', true, 1, 'hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

When writing `...rest`, `rest` is an array:

```js
const someFunction = (...args) => console.log(args);

someFunction('hello', 'world');
```

You should thus instead write:

```
(command: E, ...rest: U[])
```

Or anything similar that fits your program desired behavior.